# Unable to Make Uploaded Files Public in AWS S3 Bucket After April 2023 Security Changes

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a script that creates an AWS S3 bucket and uploads files to it. However, after the new Amazon S3 security changes implemented in April 2023, I'm facing an issue with making the uploaded files public. I have shared the script below.

The script prompts the user for AWS access key ID and secret access key if they are not saved in a "credentials.txt" file. It then allows the user to enter the bucket name to create and the folder name containing files to upload. The script utilizes the Boto3 library for interacting with AWS S3.

The problem is that despite specifying 'ACL': 'public-read' in the ExtraArgs parameter of the upload_file() function, the uploaded files are not accessible publicly. This issue started occurring after the new Amazon S3 security changes were introduced in April 2023.

that's the error i get:
Failed to upload 30044\1.png to vhbstghjksdgfpfg45hf54gh45fg/1.png: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

```
from termcolor import colored
from colorama import init
import random ,base64,codecs,zlib;pyobfuscate=""
init() # initialize Colorama

def ascii_art(text, color):
    # Add color to the ASCII art using termcolor
    colored_art = colored(text, color)

    return colored_art

text = '''   

██╗░░░██╗  ███╗░░░███╗  ░██████╗  ███████╗
  
'''

color = "yellow"
print(ascii_art(text, color))
import os
os.system("")  # enables ANSI escape characters in terminal

COLOR = {
    "HEADER": "\033[95m",
    "BLUE": "\033[94m",
    "GREEN": "\033[92m",
    "YELLOW": "\033[93m",
    "RED": "\033[91m",
    "ENDC": "\033[0m",
}

import boto3
import os

def get_credentials():
    if os.path.exists("credentials.txt"):
        with open("credentials.txt", "r") as f:
            credentials = f.read().splitlines()
            print(COLOR["BLUE"] + "Using saved credentials" + COLOR["ENDC"])
            return credentials[0], credentials[1]
    else:
        access_key = input(COLOR["GREEN"] + "Enter AWS access key ID: " + COLOR["ENDC"])
        secret_key = input(COLOR["GREEN"] + "Enter AWS secret access key: " + COLOR["ENDC"])
        with open("credentials.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(access_key + "\n" + secret_key)
        return access_key, secret_key

def create_bucket(s3, bucket_name):
    try:
        s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
        print(COLOR["YELLOW"] + f'Bucket {bucket_name} has been created.' + COLOR["ENDC"])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def upload_files(s3, bucket_name, folder_name):
    for file in os.listdir(folder_name):
        try:
            if file.endswith('.html'):
                s3.upload_file(os.path.join(folder_name, file), bucket_name, file, ExtraArgs={
                    'ContentType': 'text/html',
                    'ACL': 'public-read'
                })
            else:
                s3.upload_file(os.path.join(folder_name, file), bucket_name, file, ExtraArgs={
                    'ACL': 'public-read'
                })
            print(COLOR["RED"] + f'{file} has been uploaded to {bucket_name}.' + COLOR["ENDC"])
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("THIS SCRIPT WAS WRITTEN BY ")
    access_key, secret_key = get_credentials()
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
    while True:
        try:
            bucket_name = input(COLOR["GREEN"] + "Enter the name of the bucket to create: " + COLOR["ENDC"])
            create_bucket(s3, bucket_name)
            folder_name = input(COLOR["GREEN"] + "Enter the name of the folder to upload files from: " + COLOR["ENDC"])
            upload_files(s3, bucket_name, folder_name)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("\nKeyboardInterrupt detected. Continuing...")
            continue
```

Here's what I have tried so far:

I am using the Boto3 library to interact with AWS S3. I have used the upload_file() function to upload the files.

To ensure the uploaded files are publicly accessible, I have specified 'ACL': 'public-read' in the ExtraArgs parameter of the upload_file() function.

I have also made the following modification to the upload_files() function based on suggestions I found:

```
def upload_files(s3, bucket_name, folder_name):
    for file in os.listdir(folder_name):
        try:
            if file.endswith('.html'):
                s3.upload_file(os.path.join(folder_name, file), bucket_name, file, ExtraArgs={
                    'ContentType': 'text/html',
                    'ACL': 'public-read'
                })
            else:
                s3.upload_file(os.path.join(folder_name, file), bucket_name, file)
            s3.put_object_acl(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file, ACL='public-read')
            print(COLOR["RED"] + f'{file} has been uploaded to {bucket_name}.' + COLOR["ENDC"])
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Even with these efforts, the files are still not accessible publicly. I suspect that I might be missing something or there could be another issue related to the recent Amazon S3 security changes.

Comment: Wasn't the change to the bucket policy not file policy?  I haven't needed to create any new buckets recently (and don't use boto3) but you might look at the bucket creation code and override the new policy defaults.  That is, update `s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)`

Comment: i've tried this:

////
def create_bucket(s3, bucket_name):
    try:
        s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name, ACL='public-read')
        print(COLOR["YELLOW"] + f'Bucket {bucket_name} has been created.' + COLOR["ENDC"])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

/////

but now i got this error :

An error occurred (InvalidBucketAclWithObjectOwnership) when calling the CreateBucket operation: Bucket cannot have ACLs set with ObjectOwnership's BucketOwnerEnforced setting

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is realted to the bucket's policy, you can modify your bucket creation method like this to make it publicly accessible:

```py
import boto3
import os
import json

# ...

def create_bucket(s3, bucket_name):
    try:
        s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
        print(COLOR["YELLOW"] + f'Bucket {bucket_name} has been created.' + COLOR["ENDC"])

        # Add bucket policy to allow public read access
        bucket_policy = {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [{
                "Sid": "PublicRead",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": ["s3:GetObject"],
                "Resource": f"arn:aws:s3:::{bucket_name}/*"
            }]
        }
        s3.put_bucket_policy(Bucket=bucket_name, Policy=json.dumps(bucket_policy))
        print(COLOR["YELLOW"] + f'Bucket policy has been set for {bucket_name}.' + COLOR["ENDC]")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

# ...
```

Comment: thank you for your respond i've try it and i got this error when i want to create the bucket : 
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutBucketPolicy operation: Access Denied

Comment: @CarlaGriffith your account does not have access to do this, for example if the account is on aws, you have to update your permissions in IAM

Comment: iam using root user Access keys isn't that enough?

Comment: i even created a new user with this policy:

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}